# group by dates and make mathematics on it using linq

Tags: c#, linq, datatable, date-arithmetic

I have datatable looks like this:

```
| date            |  value |
| 1/1/2013  10:28 | 5      |
| 1/1/2013  10:29 | 6      |
| 2/1/2013  01:54 | 6.5    |
| 2/1/2013  02:24 | 6.7    |
| 2/1/2013  03:14 | 8      |
```

1. I want to group the table into days.
2. then to calculate the avarage value of every group.
3. then to make avarage of all the values I calculated in step 2.

is there any good way to do it through linq ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

of course you can use linq for this purpose:

```
var results = from p in list
              group p by p.date.Date into g
              select new { date = g.Key, value = g.Average(p=> p.value) };

var endAverage = results.Average(x => x.value);
```

Comment: assuming that your data are in a list of type List<MyType>, which MyType is a class with two property, date DateTime, value double